# Как спарсить атрибуты XML C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Есть xml файл

```js
<toplevel>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keyshot"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keystone"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keystore explorer"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keyshape"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keysight technologies"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keys eset smart security"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keyshia cole"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keystone species"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keys"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="keysmart"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
</toplevel>
```

3 часа я пытался спарсить данные из data=" " Вроде все казалось легко, но что то не пошло, смотрел ответы на вопросы по теме, и так и не понял как это сделать.
В итоге плюнул и сделал вот так

```js
string s = Doc.OuterXml;
            string reg = "(?<=data=\").*?(?=\")";
            Regex regex = new Regex(reg);
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(s);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Совпадений не найдено");
            }
```

Как я понял xml документ можно обрабатывать через LINQ и через System.Xml, оба способа мне показались очень сложными. Если вас не затруднит напишите пожалуйста как это сделать правильно а не через регулярные выражения. И почему не стоит использовать regex для таких вещей? Ведь вроде удобно и легко.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как говорится LINQ to XML вам в помощь...

Вам понадобиться:

- Класс `XDocument` и его 3 метода:

  - `.Element()` - Берем один объект.
  - `.Elements()` - Берем коллекцию объектов.
  - `.Attribute()` - Получаем атрибут данной "ноды".

В итоге получаем код:

```
var compleated = XDocument.Load("testFile.txt").Element("toplevel").Elements("CompleteSuggestion");
foreach (var item in compleated)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Element("suggestion").Attribute("data").Value);
}
```

- `XDocument.Load("testFile.txt")` - загрузили некий документ.
- `.Element("toplevel")` - взяли `<toplevel>` из этого документа.
- `.Elements("CompleteSuggestion")` - из предыдущего узла взяли все `<CompleteSuggestion>`.
- `foreach (var item in compleated)` - циклом проходимся по полученным объектам.

  - `item.Element("suggestion")` - у каждого объекта, который дает нам цикл мы берем `<suggestion/>`.
  - `.Attribute("data")` - получаем атрибут `data` у найденного объекта.
  - `.Value` - ну и забираем его значение.

Результат:

```
keyshot
keystone
keystore explorer
keyshape
keysight technologies
keys eset smart security
keyshia cole
keystone species
keys
keysmart
```

---

Если надо получить только значение атрибутов, а на остальное грубо говоря пофиг, то подключаем LINQ и переписываем на нечто такое:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("testFile.txt")
    .Element("toplevel")
    .Elements("CompleteSuggestion")
    .Select(x=>x.Element("suggestion")
    .Attribute("data").Value);
```

Результатом будет коллекция из `string` значений.